# Display sqlite data to WPF app with good design?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sqlite, xaml

Is this possible?
I want to display the content of a sqlite table to look something like this image:

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvElF.png)

so far i have this method which is in a xaml.cs file:

```
        public void printHighscores()
    {
        connectToDatabase();
        string sql = "select * from Pacientes";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        int a = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        {

            System.Windows.Controls.Button newBtn = new Button();
            a++;
            newBtn.Content = reader["nombre"];
            newBtn.Name = "Button" + a;

            Wrapsito.Children.Add(newBtn);

        }
        m_dbConnection.Close();
    }
```

and the display of the method is this:

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5UsH.png)

Im using wrappanel to do so, is this the correct way to do it? 
Any tutorial, metod, workaround would be highly wanted =)
Any example, help anything to display data in a good design could help!
Thanks in advance <3
Anything could help!

Comment: this is not the wpf way of displaying list of items. checkout [WrapPanel](http://www.wpftutorial.net/WrapPanel.html)

Comment: i thought it was the closest one,  not sure how to do it  like the example shown though,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a ViewModel class where you have the name, image etc:

```
public class Paciente
{
   public int Id;

   public string Nombre;

   public string Imagen;

}
```

From your SqLite database, you can now create objects of type Paciente, and create a Custom XAML User control "Paciente.xaml" where you can design with images and all. You can then use this list of Pacientes as your list, and select the userControl Paciente.xaml as your DataTemplate.

I would search a little for MVVM and Custom Controls to lean how to do this. It is a very powerful way of creating fantastic designs.

Comment: should i search how to use MVVM first right?  kinda lost here, not sure where to begin